# GStreamer with WebRTC, OpenCV-Server-Client

Tags: c++, opencv, webrtc, gstreamer

I don’t know if I can say “I’m sorry for ask” but I spent more than a week looking for a solution without success.  I have a Jetson Nano and with OpenCV I get and process an image at 4fps, I need to send this video to a web server to allow the client connected to the server get the video. Everything need to be written in C++.
Because a need a low latency I did test with GStreamer and WebRTC without success. I don’t have any web server ready, so I can use any implementation.

Anyone know where I can find some example implementation with this schema?

Comment: Rather than using WebRTC, have you looked into using RTP (or RTSP)?

Comment: What exactly problem did you get with GStreamer's WebRTC? I've did some experiments with `webrtcbin` and it works for me.

Comment: @nielsdg RTSP was my first attempt but a got almost 2 seconds of latency, I need less than 200ms.

Comment: @RSATom Could you please indicate some example? all the examples I found of webrtcbin are about send video stream from the browser, I need the appositive, "something" that allow me to send a Mat of OpenCV and view it in a browser. I can not use a direct connection with a webcam.

Comment: @Deulis sure https://github.com/WebRTSP/Native/blob/master/GstStreaming/GstTestStreamer.cpp
Also, online demo based on code from the same repo is available: http://ipcam.stream:5080/ it's running https://snapcraft.io/rtsp-to-webrtsp

Comment: @Deulis: RTSP is not going to be (that much) slower than WebRTC. Have you ever tried seeing where the latency is actually building up? If you insist on using WebRTC, there's a good chance the latency will be quite similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org) to send data to the server to then send the stream with rtp to another endpoint like gstreamer or ffmpeg.

[Here is a recording project](https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo) where data is sent from the browser -> server -> gstreamer -> file.

Mediasoup is written in c++ and has a wrapper for js.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and used [such](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/blob/master/webrtc/janus/janusvideoroom.py) example from GStreamer WebRTC official repo. It's written in Python for Janus Gateway video rooms but I think it can be easily rewritten in C++ as you need.

In the code for OpenCV, I used [V4L2Loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) as a virtual output device to be used as input for GStreamer WebRTC example.

I hope such approach may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to send it to a Web Server. In Gstreamer examples [https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-examples]. The **SendOnly** example sends a video to a Web Client Using WebRTC. You can modify it to send an OpenCV mat.